# Don't understand the following jstl tag

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

```
<c:url var="queryString" value="?${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']}"/>
```

I know `<c:url>` is used for URL rewriting. But here from where the url value is assigned to the var queryString. I don't understand the meaning of `requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']`

Comment: Next time just search in answers here by adding `is:a` to keyword, e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+javax.servlet.forward.query_string

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> The name of the request attribute that should be set by the container
>   when the forward(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) method is called. It
>   provides the original value of a path-related property of the request.
>   See the chapter "Forwarded Request Parameters" in the Servlet
>   Specification for details.

The javax.servlet.forward.query_string parameter is being set when the

```
requestDispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

is being called from the controller.